# 500 - Internal Server Error on codeigniter when autoload any library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have fresh codeigniter installation (version 2.2.6) on IIS. It works fine loading the welcome screen. But as soon as I edit the autoload.php file just by autoloading the database library:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

It gives me an internal server error.

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the webserver's errorlog?

Comment: I dont really know how to check the logs but this is what I saw in the logs:

2016-01-29 17:23:52 W3SVC1 DEMCHP990BDWEB 10.86.84.21 GET /gain/codeigniter/index.php/welcome - 443 - 10.97.225.109 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.111+Safari/537.36 PHPSESSID=m9k45o0p00nsn89vb17nfskin6;+treemenu1=none+open - demchp990bdweb.ww930.my-it-solutions.net 500 0 0 1493 504 2308

Comment: May be error in some other place

Comment: This looks like IIS needs other paths or permissions. By the way, how do you invent to combine IIS with CodeIgniter? It sounds very terrible.

Comment: @Schellingerht what's so confusing about IIS and codeigniter?

Comment: @charlietfl Personally, I dislike CodeIgniter, and IIS (specially used for hosting PHP).

Comment: @Schellingerht not a big fan of IIS either but developer doesn't always write the rules

Comment: Does DB works if you don't autoload it? If so, you are trying to load it twice and you should find in controllers where is loaded. Remove that code and stay with autoload only.

Comment: After loading database lib.. Plz show your database array.. From database.php file or chk credential

Comment: it's not just the database library. I havent touched any file aside from the autoload.php file. any library I autoload (ex. database, session) I get the error.